# determine the general solution of the given differential equation: $y'' − 4y' + 13y = e^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

determine the general solution of the given differential equation: $y'' − 4y' + 13y = e^{2x}$

I'm solving a list of supposedly simple exercises, one of the subjects is ordinary differential equations, which is where I have the most difficulty, and I've been trying to solve the above question for half an hour, one of my study strategies is to try to do it myself, and then check the result on some online calculator(mathdf) to see if I got it right, in the case of the question above, the results are not matching, and I can't see where I'm going wrong, if someone can help me with this question it would be of great help.

Comment: What is the result you got? How did you get to it? It is very hard for us to help find what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did... Also, you might find MathJax useful for writing down your equations. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: I'm new here at Math Stack Exchange, by the way, right now I'm reading the link you sent me

Comment: 2nd order ODE with constant coefficient are very well known... Check on google, you'll find a lot of method ;-)

Comment: How can anyone say where you went wrong if you don't show us what you did?

Answer (score 3):

$$
y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x),
$$

where $y_h(x)$ is a solution of a homogeneous equation $y''-4y'+13y = 0$, and $y_p(x)$ is a *particular* solution.

To solve the equation $y''-4y'+13y = 0$, one have to solve a *characteristic* equation

$$
\lambda^2-4\lambda + 13 = 0,
$$

which is a quadratic algebraic equation. The solution is
$$
\lambda_{1, 2} = \frac{-(-4)\pm \sqrt{(-4)^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot 13}}{2\cdot 1} = 2\pm 3i \Rightarrow 
$$

$$
y_h(x) = C_1e^{2x}\cos(3x) + C_2e^{2x}\sin(3x).
$$

The solution $y_p(x)$ can be found in a form $y_p(x) = Ae^{2x}$. Then,

$$
y_p'(x) = 2Ae^{2x}, \text{ and } y_p''(x) = 4Ae^{2x}.
$$

Substituting $y_p(x), y_p'(x), \text{ and }y_p''(x)$ into the equation, one has

$$
4Ae^{2x}-4\cdot 2Ae^{2x} + 13Ae^{2x} = e^{2x} \Leftrightarrow 9A = 1 \Leftrightarrow A = \frac{1}{9},
$$

and $y_p(x) = \frac{1}{9}e^{2x}$.

Finally, the general solution is
$$
y(x) = y_h(x)+y_p(x) = C_1e^{2x}\cos(3x) + C_2e^{2x}\sin(3x) + \frac{1}{9}e^{2x}.
$$